# How well to decompose the subject area into OOP?

Tags: oop, analysis, separation-of-concerns, decomposition

Please recommend how to properly **decompose the domain in the OOP** ?

**We need an in-depth book for this topic.**
Please do not write these books (GOF , Head First Object Oriented Analysis , Object-Oriented Software Construction 'Bertrand Meyer').
if someone has a recommendation **(book, reference)** Please write
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend **Object Thinking** by David West. It contradicts a lot of what I have learned, and helped me in some way when decomposing the problem domain. I am still currently half-way through it.

Answer (score 1):

**Description of the reason for the problem**

The general problem of some Object Oriented Analysts and Designers is **Lack of mastery of basic concepts**.

In order to learn object oriented domain modeling, you should dominate the subject of Object Oriented Analysis and Design **in-depth**. So you should study more basic and **fundamental books rather than practical books**.

Best book that learned Object Oriented Concepts in-depth is:
**Object-Oriented Software Construction, Bertrand Meyer, Second Edition**

Another tutorial book about Object Oriented Analysis and Design that learned the concepts **in-depth** is: **Object-Oriented Analysis and Design, with Applications, Third Edition, Grady Booch et al.**

**After** studying basic and fundamental concepts you can learn **EASILY** and **QUICKLY** some other practical books like the books that you mentioned in your question.